# Can I reuse a docker container that requires user input? EOF error occurs when using docker container start

Tags: python, docker, input, containers, eof

Code will be provided below, but let me summarize up front first.

I created a simple Python script that asks what the user's name is for demonstration purposes. I then made the image and ran it using: `docker run -it docker:example`. This works as expected, I get the prompt asking for my name, and I can enter it without issue and the docker container exits.

Now instead of creating a new container the next time I want to run the program, I run `docker container start <container_name>` This throws the following issue **EOFError: EOF when reading a line**

I am relatively new to Docker, but from what I can tell the `docker run` command has the `-t` option which creates a needed pseudo-TTY for input, which the `docker container start` command lacks.

**My objective is to re-use the same docker container without having to create a new one each time with the `run` command.**

**Dockerfile**

```
# Set base image (host OS)
FROM python:3.8

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /src

# Copy the content of the local src directory to the working directory
COPY src/ .

# Command to run on container start
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

**main.py**

```py
name = input('Enter your name: ')
print(f'Hello', name)
```

**Steps to reproduce my use case**

1. `docker build -t docker:example`
2. `docker run -it docker:example` //works as expected
3. `docker container start <container_name>` //Fails

Step 3 fails with the **EOFError: EOF when reading a line**, I tried using the -ai options as well.

**Output**

```
docker container start -ai dockerExample
Enter your name: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    name = input('Enter your name: ')
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: `docker run` a new container isn't particularly expensive and I'd just do that.  (I almost never `docker start` a container; `docker rm` the stopped container and `docker run` a new one instead.)

Comment: This may be true, however my particular use case I am prompted for a 2FA code. If I use `docker run` I will always be prompted for input. If I use the pre-existing validated container, I won't have to provide the 2FA code for a few days. So I do have a small use case where re-using the container has a benefit. @David Maze, I really appreciate the input, thank you for taking the time to reply!